# Django cuts off values from the char fields in Model after save/create method?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

I've been trying to wrap my head around the following: whenever I submit a form that involves some text input in Django, a character is missing when the transaction is fulfilled. I am not only having the same problem with my own forms, but also those managed by allauth (the email always has the first letter missing when user registers). When I use the debugger to see what values are being passed in through the model, it all looks good. What happense after save() is called? Could it be sqllite causing the issue? Appreciate any pointers!

Here is the code (I included some debug screenshots):

```
@login_required
def create_recurring_task(request):
    new_task = RecurringTask.objects.create(name=request.POST['name'],
                                            cloned_task_notion_id=request.POST['id'],
                                            cloned_task_url=request.POST['url'],
                                            database_id=request.POST['database-id'],
                                            owner=request.user)
    tasks = request.user.tasks.filter(database_id=request.POST['database-id']
    return render(request, "tasks/partials/recurring-user-tasks-list.html", {'tasks': tasks})
```

[image: Result int he debugger]

[image: Result in the Database]

Edit: My User Model as Requested (it's just the default for DjangoX)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Edit 2: Form powered by HTMX

```
<form class="d-inline-block align-self-end ml-auto" hx-post="{% url 'create-recurring-task' %}"
      hx-target="#recurring-tasks-{{ db_task.db_id }}">
    <input
            name="name"
            type="hidden"
            value="{{db_task.title}}"
    />
    <input
            name="url"
            type="hidden"
            value="{{db_task.url}}"
    />
    <input
            name="id"
            type="hidden"
            value="{{db_task.id}}"
    />
    <input
            name="database-id"
            type="hidden"
            value="{{db_task.db_id}}"
    />
    <button
            class="btn btn-success"
            type="submit"
    >
        +
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: hm do you use the base user model or did you inherit from it? If so plz post your user model

Comment: Updated it! Let me know if there are more ways I can help...

Comment: can you please also post the form and the html

Comment: Also added it - I'm using HTMX which means it just works like AJAX.

Comment: this is happening to me for all models that I'm inheriting. Driving me absolutely mad. Is this a django bug?

Comment: No idea Paul, I started a new project and it was gone - sorry that I don't have a fix for you!